# Resource leak error in java in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory-leaks

> resouce leak: "sc" is not closed.

What does it mean by *"sc" is not closed*?

```
public static void main(String atr[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    int sum=0;
    while(a<0){
        int r=a%10;
        a=a/10;
        sum = sum + r*r*r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any resource that you may open for input/output operations must be closed after you are done using them, otherwise, a memory leak may occur

Answer (score 0):

It wants you to close your scanner. When I put it in my code it did not prevent it from running, just gave a warning message. If you want to get rid of the error simply put

```
sc.close();
```

at the end of your code and the warning should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code below

```
static Scanner sc ;
public static void main(String atr[]){
  try{
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    int sum=0;
        while(a<0){
            int r=a%10;
            a=a/10;
            sum = sum + r*r*r;
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printstacktrace();
    }finally{
        if(sc != null){
        sc.close()
        }
    }
}
```

You have to close scanner object after you are done  :)

Comment: But it is showing error of static variable error related to sc

Comment: there is an error . SC is taken as local variable which is not initialized while checking the if condition .